# Passing Constructors as arguments(language design)

Tags: javascript, language-design

I am trying to create my own language and would like to  know if passing a constructor would be a possible feature i.e
The syntax used is based on javascript and a few other languages, but for my option, I am considering a compiled runtime and would like to know if this feature would be possible. In a compiled language as structured below

```js
// $ defines a variable declaration.
        class Token{
           static test(string){
              return this.regex.test(string)
           }
        }

        // javascript regex syntax used.
        class Identifier:Token{
          // bettere regex used 
          static regex = /[a-zA-Z]*/
        }
        class Equals: Token{
          static regex =  /=/
        }

        class Dollar: Token{
          static regex = /\$/
        }

        class MyLanguage(String code,Parser ...parsers){

          
           
          private tokens = []
          
          static tokens = [Identifier,,Dollar]
          
          init{
             tokenize();
          }
          
          get parser(){
             // parsers passed in constructor i.e kotlin syntax
             for($parser in parsers){
                 // tokens part of lang instance on tokenize success
                 parser.shouldParse(tokens)
             }
             throw "Can  not parser code"
          }
          
          tokenize(){
            // not really reasonable but not what I am using
            code = code.explode(" ")
           
            
            // find valid token and instanciate
            for($s in code){
                for($token in self.tokens){
                  // test a string against a token class i.e Identifier.test("int")
                   if(token.test(s)){
                      // instanciating class constructor
                      tokens.push(new token(code))
                   }
                }
            }
            
          }
        }

        class Parser{
             static shouldParse(tokens){
                tokens =  tokens.copy
                // do parse section validation test on tokens copy
             }
        }

        class VariableDeclarationParser : Parser{

        }
        // expected tokens 
        // Identifier Identifier Equals Number
        let lang =new Language("int a = 12",VariableDeclarationParser)
```

Comment: It is `class Equals extends Token {` Also `this.regex` is not defined, use `this.constructor.regex`

Comment: This question seems more suited to [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I don't know if SO deals with language design before the language is implemented.

Comment: @vlaz this is not about language design though.

Comment: @JonasWilms "*I am trying to create my own language*" - I thought it was?

Comment: @vlaz maybe I'm not getting the actual question, however the code as presented is full of grammatical errors, so it is hard to tell wether that is the problem

Comment: @JonasWilms the way I read it is that OP is trying to create a new programming language that is based (somewhat) on JS but wants to know if a feature (passing a constructor) can be implemented. To be honest, I don't really grasp the question, either but that's what I got out of it. I'm not sure if the code given is example of the question or the interpreter/compiler/something else.

Comment: Where does the code pass a constructor as argument to a function? If the function expects a constructor to be passed there should not be an issue with the procedure.

Comment: The regex for Identifier:Token should be: `static regex = /[a-zA-Z]+/`

Comment: It is language-design  and it is not about the syntax issues please the code written is purely in my designed language and seem to me it can be partially understood now what I am asking is if the token initializer section would work in a compiled language as we can not do static tokens = [Identifier,...] etc in any compiled language I know so far?

Comment: class Token is never initialized as it is supposed to be abstruct that section if just to bring in together why I need constructor passing as part of my language!

Comment: PS the code is in no way fit to run. It's for demonstration of the required feature and why it is required. I can do this in proper javascript and the parser works perfect with a great design regex system but now i want my language to support such features!

Comment: @guest271314 my question was visible from [Identifier] section but have added some changes to what the code constructor

Comment: @Jonas Wilms the method is static so this is for static  and again the code is not javascript havent come up with a name yet and javascript supports the feature. if you understand you can translate to javascript you will see it runs perfect

Comment: If this is your first language, I would recommend starting with something smaller like Scheme using this [guided implementation in SICP](https://github.com/sarabander/sicp) or [Cool](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/software/cool/cool.html) which basically exists for the purposes of teaching this kind of thing.

Comment: @user633183 been looking for something like this for a while now really great help thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You're asking whether you can create an array of constructors, but it looks more like you're trying to create an array of classes. Either way, both are possible in statically typed languages given some support for reflection. For example in Java you can write:

```
Class<? extends Token>[] tokens = {Identifier.class, Dollar.class};
```

And there's no reason why you couldn't change the syntax to leave out the `.class` bit.

Creating an array of constructors is also possible in Java:

```
Constructor<? extends Token>[] tokens = {
    // get the constructor Identifier(String)
    Identifier.class.getConstructor(String.class),
    // get the constructor Dollar()
    Dollar.class.getConstructor()
};
```

Again, if you want your language to be heavy on that type of reflection, you can certainly introduce a more concise syntax to achieve the same.

So the answer to your question is: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Class<? extends Token> tokens = [Identifier, Dollar]

Comment: thank, and really appreciate the idea opened my mind to a somewhat better syntax Class<? extends Token> tokens = [Identifier, Dollar]